# Concurrency violation appears when I add rows and update rows in certain situation

Tags: c#, winforms, sqldataadapter

My setup is simple,

- a DataGridView binded to a BindingSource
- The BindingSource is binded to a DataTable
- The DataTable is populated by a simple `adapter.Fill(table);`

Now this works well, but since today I get this error in a certain situation.

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1
>   records.

I can reproduce it by the following

1. Add a new row to the DataGridView
2. Save to the database using `adapter.Update(Table);`
3. add another row
4. alter the value of any column, on both rows
5. try to save again using  `adapter.Update(Table);`

Now the error occurs.
I have catched the actual statement send to Sql Server using the profiler, and the statement is this :

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'UPDATE [tblDamageRegion] SET [Remarks] = @Remarks WHERE (([DamageRegionID] = @Original_DamageRegionID))',
N'@Remarks nvarchar(1),@Original_DamageRegionID int',
@Remarks=N'1',@Original_DamageRegionID=NULL
```

As you can see, the variable `@Original_DamageRegionID` is NULL
That causes no rows to be updated, and thus the error above appears.

My question is, how is it possible that the adapter does not fills this variable ?

I tried `table.AcceptChanges();` after each `adapter.Update(Table);` but it did not help
I tried `BindingSource.EndEdit();` before the  `adapter.Update(Table);` but it did not help

Comment: Can't you see the values in the Original_DamageRegionID Column in your DataGridView? If there are Nulls maybe there's something wrong with your Select Statement ...

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn No thats missing the point. There is no such column, this variable is created by the adapter and normally has the value of the key column of that row. I have no influence over it, its been done by the adapter

Comment: If it's not a column in your Datatable then it can't be used by the Update Statement ...

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn I think you should read up about how a Adapter works